# Algorithm to solve system of equations

Tags: algorithm, system, equation

What is an algorithm to solve systems of equations of this kind?

```
aX1 + bY1 + cZ1 = 0

aX2 + bY2 + cZ2 = 0

aX3 + bY3 + cZ3 = 0
```

In this case I wish to solve for `a`, `b` and `c`.

Comment: Typing your question title *verbatim* into Google's search bar leads to the Wikipedia article as the top result. *Several* algorithms are given there.

Comment: Beware: any easy answer to this question will be wrong.  The usual algorithms as presented in 1st year courses are badly unstable, often giving *wrong* results.  For certain classes of linear systems, there are very good, even optimal, algorithms, that are both fast and numerically stable.  Investigate the field of "numerical linear algebra".  Ignore anybody who gives an answer without asking more about the coefficients of the system.

Comment: @John Google now brings you here. Funny how that works.

Comment: @ParkerD It sure is. Things can change a lot in a decade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a variety of methods, but the two most well know are by [Gaussian Elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) and [Cramer's Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule). As far as algorithms go you can check out *Introduction to the Design and Analysis of Algorithms* by Anany Levitin, I know he has a nice algorithm to solve by Gaussian Elimination with cubic (n^3) runtime, but I don't remember it offhand.

Answer (score 2):

To solve a System of linear equations, there are many different techniques available.

**Gauss elimination** method (Also a variant of Gauss elimination method called **Gauss Jordan elimination** method), **Cramer's Rule** etc. are examples for different techniques used to solve system of linear equations.

Both the techniques makes use of the properties of matrices formed from the equations.

Gauss elimination has a time complexity of O(n3), where as Cramer's rule requires to find the inverse of the matrix formed by the coefficients of the linear equations in the system.

Link to the Wikipedia article on Gauss Elimination,

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination

Link to the Wikipedia article on Cramer's Rule.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule